# ASP.NET MVC Model Validation best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

There are two major methods to validate models

1. Check `Model.IsValid` in every action
2. Implement `ActionFilterAttribute` and which checks
   `!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid` every request, register it globally.

Which one do you use? What are pros/cons of them?

Comment: Pretty broad IMO. Anyway if what you have to do is just is if (!Model.IsValid) then a filter would be right. It's not always true, sometimes you need more (and more specific) logic then it has to be done in each method...

Comment: I use my custom validation, not Model.IsValid. Every model passes from it's validation lawyer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience checking `Model.IsValid` in every action is a better approach.

- allows you to use PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern easier
- sometimes specific actions are needed when user submits invalid form data
- depending on your ViewModel repopulating dictionaries may be required after invalid form submit
- allows you to display specific messages for action success/error

I would recommend global `ActionFilterAttribute` only in most basic solutions.